# CefSharp WPF for platform x64 unable to reference in another wpf project

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I have been working on embedding cefsharp browser into my wpf application.
- i have different build configuration for x86 and x64 platforms. i have converted my application to target x64.
- I have created a new WPF Application named "CefControl" to my main solution.
  - installed nuget package "CefSharp.Wpf -Version 57.0.0".
now in my CefControl project i have created a usercontrol that embeds cefsharp's chromiumBrowser Control.
I have been following the github example CefSharp.Wpf.Example to implement the control. 
i have embeded the usercontrol in a wpf window and it works like a charm!!!!

now coming to my actual requirement. i have to reference my new project CefControl to my main project. when i reference CefControl in my main project it doesnt work atall i get build issues. suddenly the chromiumbrowser control that worked fine when run directly now has a problem.

my usercontrol.xaml is unable to find cefsharp.wpf in the namespace. 
this is my code **xmlns:cef="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"**

what could be the reason. the project runs fine when run independently. i have converted my main project to x64 from anycpu tobe able to embed cefsharp control

[project properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJxsn.png)

[xaml code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gktWK.png)

Comment: Try with this NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/cef.redist.x64/3.2987.1601

Comment: Please give more details about the "build issues".  Exact error messages are helpful.

Comment: @Isma  I have been using the same package u mentioned but its not working. i have included the screenshots of the build issue.  thanks

Comment: @BradleyUffner I have attached the Image that shows the build errors and project references. 
The cefsharp references are accessible in the code behind but xaml reference throws the error.

Comment: @VijrumbhanMiryala I'm seeing the same error message in a simple test project too.  Not sure what it going on yet.

Comment: Thanks guys. Earlier i dropped CefSharp implementation for anycpu and moved on with other stuff but recently i re-looked into cefsharp implementation and it is working in my project seamlessly. 

step-1 I Changed my project target framework to 4.6.
step-2  followed option-2 as directed in the post https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1714